# SCSS rem mixin that takes multiple properties

Tags: css, sass

I'm currently using the [REM mixin](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/less-mixin-for-rem-font-sizing/) by Karl Merkli.

It works great, however I'm finding I'm writing a lot of @includes in the process. for example:

```
    @include rems(height, 1);
    @include rems(width, 1);
    @include rems(margin, 1, 0, 4, 0);
    @include rems(padding, 0.5, 1);
    // plus all other @includes Ii might use too
    @include opacity(0.7);
    @include clearfix;
    // etc
```

I'm trying to work out a way of consolidating the references to the same mixin into one. Ultimately I'm looking for a solution where I could write something similar to the following:

```
    @include rems(height, 1; width, 1; margin, 1, 0, 4, 0; padding, 0.5, 1;);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you would add more properties to mixin rem? Like this:

`@mixin rem($property, $values, $property, $values, $property, $values)`

I'm not using these mixins at all so that answer can be really stupid, but oh well, as I googled I didn't find any solutions so the only way is to modify the mixin by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to create an in-between mixin that takes a list of lists and hands each list off to the `rems` mixin:

```
@mixin multi-rems($lists) {
    @each $list in $lists {
        @include rems($list...);
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
li {
    @include multi-rems(((margin, 0, 4), (padding, 2, 3)));
}
```

Here's a [**SassMeister Gist**](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/262f3c7c97956cf3c252375f82e0626f).  Cheers.

Comment: That's excellent. I can definitely work with that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem.  Have fun!